# PHP gettext always get same language file

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

I have the code as follow:

```
$l = "whatever here";//I can put pt or en...
if($l == 'pt'){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'pt_BR';//pt
}
else{
   $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en_UK';//eng
}

$locale = $_SESSION['lang'].".utf8";
putenv("LANG=$locale"); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
//just to know
echo $locale;

$domain = 'messages';
bindtextdomain($domain, "E:/OneDrive/Software/Projects/php/public_html/Locale"); 
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');        
textdomain($domain);

//just to do the test
echo _("test");
```

I have the directory struct as follow

```
E:\OneDrive\Software\Projetos\php\public_html\Locale\en_UK\LC_MESSAGES\messages.mo
E:\OneDrive\Software\Projetos\php\public_html\Locale\pt_BR\LC_MESSAGES\messages.mo
```

But always, no matter how I set the local variable, the program always get the value from pt_BR\LC_MESSAGES\messages.mo, what is wrong?

Comment: My guess is you are using PHP on a Windows machine that is set to pt_BR. There is no way to get PHP to change Windows locales, it will throw no error but will always use the machine's locale. This happens to all of us who try to develop locally on Windows; we just can't test gettext locally. Options are: uploading to a linux test server or installing a Virtual Machine on your Windows computer. :o/

Comment: Thanks, but some time after this post, I give up...Anyway, I belive you are right